# Getting pca.explained_variance_ratio_ for all components without doing PCA twice

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I understand that `explained_variance_ratio_` can be obtained easily using PCA but will be restricted to the contribution from the first `n_components`. I was wondering if `explained_variance_ratio_` can be obtained for all components without doing PCA twice, after all the parameters are derived after having the full eigen values. This I intend to do as the matrix is huge and I am looking to reduce time in the computation.

Comment: It seems that `explained_variance_ratio_` is an attribute of `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`, so you could get it after doing PCA. Where are the second time of doing PCA?

Comment: For more information about **liginity**s comment; https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html Check the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

Yes, you can obtain the explained_variance_ratio_ for all components without doing PCA twice. When you perform PCA, you can specify the number of components you want to keep. If you don't specify this number, PCA will keep all the components.

If you want to reduce the number of components after fitting the PCA, you can do so without having to fit the PCA again. Try the folllowing:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np

pca = PCA()
pca.fit(X_train)
```

Now to print explained varience ratio:

```
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

Get the explained variance ratio for the first 10 components

```
explained_variance_ratio_10 = pca.explained_variance_ratio_[:10]
```

Comment: Thank you.  `pca.fit_transform(my_matrix)[:,:n_components]` and `pca.explained_variance_ratio_` together was the solution I was looking for.